# Best way to communicate between services in microservice architecture?

Tags: node.js, microservices

I have 2 microservice in nodejs. one user and other is courses. User service kept info of user info and also the enrolled courses id.

In  user listing i need to show the user info + course info.

how do i implement this in microservice architecture so i have not need to wait for user query to return the ids of courses and the get the course info from course service and the combined the result and return it?

I am new to microservices.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve `inter-service communication` in two different ways.

1. `Synchronous` - Directly call REST APIs of other services
2. `Asynchronous` - Implement Asynchronous messaging using Kafka or `RabbitMQ` (non-blocking)

Both ways have their own advantages and disadvantages.

I am working on `Microservices` architecture for almost a year, I am using `RabbitMQ` messaging broker. if you want a highly reliable, highly available and fast mode of communication, you must use Async way only.